# Accord gender of nouns according to the sex of a person

Tags: conditionals

I would like to conditionally add the trailing `e` depending of the sex of a person:

```
 Je soussigné, John Doe...
```

Or for a female:

```
 Je soussignée, Béatrice Dunod...
```

For this I expect two entries:

```
 \author{John Doe}
 \genre{male}
```

Of course, the gender can only be `male` or `female`.

Then I could use:

```
 Je soussigné\ifthen{\@genre is female}{e}, \@author...
```

What would be the best way to achieve this in LaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost what you wrote yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\genre#1{\gdef\@genre{#1}}
\def\female{female}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\author{John Doe}
\genre{male}
Je soussigné\ifx\@genre\female e\fi, \@author

\author{Jane Doe}
\genre{female}
Je soussigné\ifx\@genre\female e\fi, \@author
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can we raise an error of somebody does `\genre{unknown}`?

Comment: @nowox you could actually consider this a feature, if somebody enters a different string then it automatically defaults to masculin. This can accommodate non-binary users for example. But if you want you can make two commands `\genremale` and `\genrefemale` without arguments that set the two possible values, then it is not possible to set an unknown value.

Answer (score 2):

If `\genre` specified as `female` an `e` is added, otherwise, not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\genderf{female}
\newcommand\genre[1]{%
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\genderf\tmp\def\gsuffix{e}\else\def\gsuffix{}\fi
}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
 \author{John Doe}
 \genre{male}

Je soussigné\gsuffix, \@author...

 \author{Béatrice Dunod}
 \genre{female}

Je soussigné\gsuffix, \@author...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me by 20 seconds :)

Comment: @Marijn You should leave your answer, the approach isn't exactly the same.

Comment: ok, I undeleted it. Yours is more practical I think, although I suspect that the OP wants to use this inside a class so it matters less.